# Timeout when importing Google Sheet in R

Tags: r, google-apps-script, google-sheets, shiny, googlesheets4

I'm using the [googlesheets4](https://github.com/tidyverse/googlesheets4) library in R to authenticate and import a google sheet as part of my shiny app. This works well, however, from time to time, I get errors indicating:

```
Error in curl::curl_fetch_memory(url, handle = handle) : 
  Timeout was reached: [sheets.googleapis.com] Operation timed out after 10000 milliseconds with 0 out of 0 bytes received
```

Have others experienced this? I wonder if I'm importing the file too frequency (with each Shiny launch) and Google isn't happy about that.

I'm wondering if I should create a DB and figure out a way to trigger Google Sheets to update the DB whenever a new row of data is entered in the Google Sheet. Has anyone else given this a whirl?

Comment: If the problem was that you were doing it too frequently you would be getting a quota error rather than a timeout-I think. Do you know how many seconds it takes to execute when it succeeds?